# Якорь на класс - такое возможно? Как?

Tags: ajax, html, вёрстка, css, javascript

```
<div class="popup"></div>
```

url: http://example.com/.popup

Очень нужно ссылаться на класс, помогите реализовать? Ссылка пойдет в js в функцию с ajax.

Comment: а что мешает сделать так <div class="popup" id="popup"></div> http://example.com/#popup

Comment: долго придумывать id ибо их уже использовано много ))
знаю, тупость, но все же хотелось бы узнать возможно такое сделать?

Comment: А как тогда если много одинаковых классов, куда ссылаться?

Comment: в шаблоне этот класс используется однажды

Comment: К тому же вариант с id почему-то не работает
$('.popup_box').load('/includes/popup_product/'+entry+'#popupid');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы `load` делаете  :) load ничего не делает, кроме как читает html и вставляет его, или куски его в блок, в вашем случае наверное надо

```
$('.popup_box').load('/includes/popup_product/'+entry+' .popup');
```

а лучше сразу генерируйте блок нужного вида по ajax запросу.

а ещё лучше отдавайте на ajax запрос ajax ответ, этим вы сэкономите 10-100 Ватт мирового электричества на 1000 посещений.

[читаем про load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), **allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted**. This is achieved with a **special syntax for the url parameter**. If **one or more space characters** are included in the string, **the portion of the string following the first space** is assumed to be a **jQuery selector** that determines the content to be loaded.

Comment: Ну это не я придумал... желание заказчика - закон )
Спасибо

Comment: Заказчик вам говорит как писать  и что надо выдавать ? Если он придумал термин "якорь" для этого случая, то вам лучше договориться с ним что он не будет диктовать вам код или пусть сам пишет.

Comment: Заказчик просит модальное окно (popup) аяксом. К коду, конечно, жестких требований нет, в этой области у меня мало опыта, чтобы что-то изящное придумать. Термин "якорь" использовал я, т.к. по-другому не знаю как назвать ))) url разве что...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю можно придумать универсальный способ по селекторам:

```
http://example.com/#.popup
http://example.com/##inp
http://example.com/#footer

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $search_element = $(location.hash.slice(1));
    if($search_element.length > 0) {
        $(window).scrollTop($search_element.offset().top);            
    }
});
```